# How to keep the value of select oneRadio checked depending on input text?

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have a `selectOneRadio` control in my `.jsf` file. I need to keep one of the `selectItem` checked based on the previous input field. If the input field is not empty then one of the options in the `selectOneRadio` has to be checked.
This is what I have done so far,

**radio.xhtml**

```
<tr>
    <td><h:outputText class="phone" value="#{srcBundle.phone_c}" /></td>
    <td><h:inputText id="phoneNo" class="phoneNo" 
                        title="#{srcBundle.phone}"
                        disabled="#{TxnResponseBean.loadSuccessMsg}" 
                        value="#{SourceBean.phoneNo}" autocomplete="off"
                        size="25" />
        <h:selectOneRadio id="callType" name="callType" value="#{SourceBean.callType}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="CHAT" itemLabel="#{srcBundle.chat}"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemValue="CALL" itemLabel="#{srcBundle.call}"></f:selectItem>
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**radio.js**

```
var selected = "CHAT"
if($('[id*=phoneNo]').val().length > 0){
    if($('input:radio[id*=callType]').is(':checked') == false) {
        $("input:radio[id*=callType][value=" + selected + "]").attr('checked', true);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Then what happen with this code?

Comment: It's not working. Gave an alert but it's not showing up.

Comment: try `.prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Hint: when asking questions about requirements in the client side, then you should not show the server side (JSF) code, but instead its generated client side code (HTML). Rightclick page in browser, do *View Source* and copy/normalize the relevant piece. Replace the server side code in your question with that. This way jQuery users can better answer your question. Most of them have no idea which HTML code exactly that JSF code generates and can therefore only make guesses. In other words, you should present the problem in flavor of plain HTML/JS code.

Comment: Debug your code more, put `console.log` in every `if` and check when exactly it fails and then use this information for correcting your mistake. Also where do you invoke this jQuery script? `$(document).ready` or some listener?

Answer (score 0):

As I had to give a fix for this the same day and since the line to keep the radio button selected didn't work, I gave the below code, making it mandatory for the user to select one of the options.

```
if($('[id*=phoneNo]').val().length > 0){
if ($('[id*=callType]').is(":checked") == false ){
    $('#msghere').html("Please select one of the options").css("color","red");
    return false;    
}
```

Thanks all for your time.